# Trouble with registerCpRoutes()

Tags: plugin-development, routing

I'm trying to add some custom routes for my plugin, but it's throwing a 400 CHttpException for `invalidActionParams` when accessing `largeupload/folders/2` as an example.

```php
public function registerCpRoutes ()
{
return array(
    'largeupload'                           => array( 'action' => 'largeUpload/index' ),
    'largeupload/folders'                   => array( 'action' => 'largeUpload/folder/index' ),
    'largeupload/folders/new'               => array( 'action' => 'largeUpload/folder/edit' ),
    'largeupload/folders/(?P<folderId>\d+)' => array( 'action' => 'largeUpload/folder/edit' ),
);
}
```

My controller is called `LargeUpload_Folder`, and my action `actionEdit()`.

```php
public function actionEdit ($variables = [ ])
{
    /* Simplified */
    if ( isset($variables['folderId']) ) {
    }
    else {
    }

    $this->renderTemplate('largeupload/LargeUpload_Edit', [
    ]);
}
```

If I remove `$variables = [ ]` from the action parameters, it doesn't return an error anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is caused by not including `array` in the function parameter, preceding the variable.

Changing to `public function actionEdit (array $variables = [ ])` should do the trick.

As a bonus - can anyone explain why? Seems like the $variables variable needs to be cast as an array?

Comment: Yes indeed. Would love to know why!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to retrieve the route variables inside your controller action and not pass anything into the function as a parameter :

```
public function actionEdit() 
{
    $routeParams = craft()->urlManager->getRouteParams();
    $folderId = $routeParams['variables']['folderId'];

    //Do stuff with $folderId

    $this->renderTemplate('largeupload/LargeUpload_Edit', []);
}
```